# autolayout view resizes upon interaction

Tags: ios, autolayout

Within a container view, I have a subview constrained to 8 pixels from the top/bottom/left/right of viewController's view. There is a button that adds an (non-autolayout) view inside of it, and another button that causes an (autolayout) view to expand below it. When the view loads, everything is as it should be, but as soon as either of the two buttons are pressed, the view in question shrinks another 8 pixels or so in width.

I've tried calling layoutIfNeeded() at a couple points in the script, but that hasn't worked. Does anybody know what might be going on here? Is there some conflict because I'm mixing autolayout with non-constrained views?

Comment: You're going to need to share code or upload project to GitHub and share a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with it for a couple of hours, I found that changing the way the view was constrained in IB fixed the problem.

I don't understand why this worked, but incase anybody else ever runs into a similar problem, instead of constraining the left/right to container view, try constraining the width of the view to be equal to the container view (minus something if you want) and add a center in container constraint.